# Set android default launcher

Tags: android

I am making an kid mode app like this app (Nester) on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.mindquake.nester

In that app, after choosing some apps for kids, when people click "GO TO KIDMOD" button

1. A launcher chooser will appear - just the first time (choose Nester launcher as "always")
2. After using the app, people have to do nothing but exit and the previous launcher (Ex: Asus default launcher) is set programmatically
3. The next time people use this Nester app, the Nester launcher is already set (no launcher picker)

My question is: how can I implement my custom launcher like that?

My KidModActivity.java

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.KidModeActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Are you looking something like this ? https://shabbirdhangot.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/change-application-name-and-launcher-icon-runtime/

Comment: Can you explain more bro? @ShabbirDhangot